# Cannot use visual studio 2019 ssh debug with raspberry pi 4

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, raspberry-pi, console-application, raspberry-pi3

I'm using **Visual Studio** and **Raspberry PI 4** for my personal project.
For now, I'm making a small console application and successfully copied and ran on **Raspberry PI 4**
I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/debugging-your-net-core-3-app-on-your-raspberry-pi-with-visual-studio-2019-9662348e79d9) to setup remote debugger from **Visual Studio 2019** to my **Raspberry PI 4**.

Everything seemed to be fine, until I **Attach to process**
When I entered my Raspberry information and click on Connect, there is one error popup appeared:

[image]

**Unable to connect to pi@raspberrypi. An operation is not legal in the current state**.

With the input information, I can remote to my Raspberry normally.

Anything wrong with my settings ?

Thank you,

Comment: I had the same problem today, opend a bug at microsoft forums (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1161746/attach-to-process-using-ssh-not-working-visual-stu.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Alan Shurack (from the microsoft forums) there is a workaround for the problem of the Ssh debugging in Visual Studio 2019 [16.7.2] (It defenetly worked at version [16.5.4])

Workaround:

Adding and connecting to the connection under Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager will solve the problem.

Search for "Edit and Set Default Remote SSH Connections" in the release notes: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-7-releases/

The issue with visual studio is being fixed and can be viewed in this thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1161746/attach-to-process-using-ssh-not-working-visual-stu.html

Comment: Thank's for the shout out!!!  Glad I could help the community!